# How can I boot into a USB device on a MacBook when there's no boot menu?

Tags: boot, usb, macbook

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my white MacBook (circa 2007 or so) because I didn't have any use for it anymore.  I chose to wipe everything and install Ubuntu over everything.  I'm trying to install Kali Linux from a USB by booting up the computer and holding the "option" key once the white boot screen comes up.  All I get is a mouse cursor and no other boot options.  Also, all I get when I boot up is a white screen, then Ubuntu starts.  What am I doing wrong here? Or did I totally overwrite my boot?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your USB stick isn't been recognised.

The Mac will boot from USB sticks but they need the correct partition scheme (MSDOS in this case). It's possible either the boot flag isn't active or the partition isn't recognised (needs to be FAT32).

The white screen you get while waiting for Ubuntu to load is perfectly normal. It's because Apple has proprietary firmware in there to display the boot screen. So long as Ubuntu pops up eventually, you can be sure it's fine.

I recommend writing an OpenELEC image to your USB device (it's small and boots rapidly into Kodi) to eliminate any other possible issues.

One you know that's working, you can safely put Kali on the stick and work from there.

You can download the 64-bit OpenELEC here: http://openelec.tv/get-openelec